# Java regex word bounderies

Tags: java, regex

I want to create regex, that will match second names with whitespaces and dashes, like:

```
Smith-Wright
Smith
Smith Wright
```

But if you will enter just - or whitespace, it shouldn't work. For now I have a regex like `^[a-zA-Z\s\-]+$`, but it watches words with only - and whitespaces. How to create regex that will match words with only my separators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for the kind of names you want to match,

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - Match a name consisting of alphabets one or more characters
- `(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*` - Additionally match more name part provided it is space or hyphen separated.
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rKll4E/2)**

Comment: But it's not matches just "Smith". What I should add to match this?

Comment: If you just want to match `Smith` just change last `+` to `*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rKll4E/2/) which will make the later part zero or more and hence optional

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your post correctly, you want to match:

- "Smith-Wright"
- "Smith"
- "Smith Wright"

but not

- "-"
- " "
- "-Wright"
- " Wright"

If that's correct, you can use:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+([ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

You can put your separators in place of `[ -]`.